# How to implement retry mechanism if the shell script execution got failed?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I am trying to execute shell script in Python code. And so far everything is looking good.

Below is my Python script which will execute a shell script. Now for an example sake, here it is a simple Hello World shell script.

```
jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash\\necho Hello world 1\\n"}'
j = json.loads(jsonStr)

shell_script = j['script']

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if stderr:
   print "Shell script gave some error"
   print stderr
else:
   print stdout
   print "end" # Shell script ran fine.
```

Now what I am looking for is, suppose for whatever reason whenever I am executing my shell script from Python code and it got failed for whatever reason. Then that means `stderr` won't be empty. So now I want to retry executing the shell script again, let's say after sleeping for couple of milliseconds?

Meaning is there any possibility of implementing of retry mechanism if the shell script execution got failed? Can I retry for 5 or 6 times? Meaning is it possible to configure this number as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
MAX_TRIES = 6

# ... your other code ...

for i in xrange(MAX_TRIES):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
    if stderr:
       print "Shell script gave some error..."
       print stderr
       sleep(0.05) # delay for 50 ms
    else:
       print stdout
       print "end" # Shell script ran fine.
       break
```

Comment: `for TRY in xrange`? Is this syntactically correct? I'd expect a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: For those times when you want a descriptive variable name and have this issue, `attempt` is a good synonym for 'try' ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel -- yes! :-) Actually if I were writing this for myself I would have used `_` as the iterator variable, as that is conventionally used as a throwaway/unused name, but I thought that might confuse things more in case the OP wasn't familiar with that.

Comment: Apparently some people don't like `_` for that purpose because some alternative REPLs (e.g. the one supplied with IronPython, IIRC) give it a special meaning (it stores the value of the previous expression). But IMO this objection is quite silly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
maxRetries = 6
retries = 0

while (retries < maxRetries):
    doSomething ()
    if errorCondition:
        retries += 1
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But how would I integrate this with my current code? As in my python script, I am executing a shell script and I want to retry if it got failed for whatever reason.

Comment: If your code is not cargo-cult, you should be able to easily integrate it. The `doSomething` is your subprocess call and the `errorCondition` is the error condition as specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a decorator? Seems like a very clear way.
You can read about them here https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary. (Retry decorator)